# Javascript Drag and Drop Script

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

Okay, so I have questions about two things.  Look at my drag and drop script on: http://bouncygames.org/smell.php.  First of all, when I click the X button on the draggable window I made, I need to click it twice, the first time I click it, things get all messed up, then I have to click it again for everything to disappear.  **How do I make it so I can only click the X one, to get the window div to disappear**  Also, I want it so only if you drag the TITLE place, it drags, not the main part of the div. **How can I make it so I can control the window with only the title?**  Thanks.

Comment: onclick="setVisibility('draggable');" is the function as I can see. I think you need to pass a this to your function like onclick="setVisibility('draggable',this);" and then use jquery in the function like $(obj).hide();

Comment: Can you use some external library like jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or better

```
function setVisibility(id) {


 document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';

    //What is the rest here?
    if(document.getElementById('aid').value=='Hide Layer'){
    document.getElementById('aid').value = 'Show Layer';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }else{
    document.getElementById('aid').value = 'Hide Layer';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example for you where:

- The dialog is dragged using only the title bar.
- The close button closes the dialog.

I know it is not a answer with deal with your code and I'm using jQuery and jQueryUI (the draggable module), but I think that using this approach would be better since the draggable issues are well controled by a tested library like jQueryUI.

Tale a look: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/s9T4b/